# Word for "reporting a table"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

In an article, I need to report my results in the form of a table. Also I want to show (exactly copy the same table in my article with proper citation) the corresponding table from a paper (showing the results of that paper) and then discuss the similarities and differences of the two tables (showing my results and the other papers' results). What verb should I use for showing the table of the other table? For example:
This table corresponds to Table 3 of paper X, which we report in Table IV.

The questions is that what verb I should use instead of report? something like copy? repeat? show?

Comment: *Repeat* and *reproduce* are good; consider also ***quote***.

Comment: Could you explain more? When to use each one?

Answer (score 1):

You can say that you *reproduce* the table in your new paper.

> **Reproduce** *verb*
>   1. Produce a copy of: *his works are reproduced on postcards and posters*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reproduce)